# How to select a region in space from a pandas dataframe where the coordinates of let's say a ball are specified and its diameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where the xyz coordinates of a ball are specified and its diameter, too. It basically is how a ball falls from certain height in time t. I want to analyze the region around the ball using python. I need to select the region which is at a distance of 2r from the center of the ball and I only have to analyze the lower half (semicircular region) of the ball.

Comment: I think a sample of the data (as **text**) and the matching expected output would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Basically, it is a function given coordination's of a point check if it will be in the the neighborhood of a point in df.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2],'y':[5,7],'z':[13,16], 'd':[2,3]})
def ss(row, point):
     sp = (row['x']-point[0])**2 + (row['y'] - point[1])**2 + (row['z'] - point[2])**2 < 2*row['d']**2
     if sp and point[2]<=row['z']:
        return True
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    print(ss(row, [1,6,15.5]))
```